# How to toggle class for clicked button in for loop?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

trying to add post to bookmark.
posts are on home page with in for loop. I have trouble getting toggle class while clicking on add bookmark button for individual post.

**Django view**

```
@login_required
def add_post_bookmark(request):
    ''' add post to bookmark '''
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        result = ''
        is_bookmark = False
        id_ =  request.POST.get('id')
        post = Post.objects.get(id=id_)
        if post.bookmarks.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            post.bookmarks.remove(request.user)
            is_bookmark = False
            post.save()
            result = post.get_bookmarks_count()
        else:
            post.bookmarks.add(request.user)
            is_bookmark = True
            post.save()
            result = post.get_bookmarks_count()

        return JsonResponse({'result': result, 'bookmark_count': post.bookmarks.all().count(), 'post_id': id_, 'is_bookmark': is_bookmark})
```

**Ajax**

```
 // bookmarks posts
    $(document).on('click', '#bookmark_add', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var bookmarkCount;
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        $.ajax ({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{% url "users:add-post-bookmark" %}',
            data: {
                'id': id,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                action: 'post'
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#'+id).empty().append(response['bookmark_count']);
                console.log(response);
                this_id = $(this).data("data-id");  //("id")
                console.log(this_id);  // undefined
                $(this).find('i').toggleClass("fad fa-bookmark far fa-bookmark");
            },
            error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
                console.log("Error bookmarking post!");
            }
        });
    })
```

**index.Html**

```
    <span id="{{post.id}}" class="bookmark_coun text-muted">{{ post.get_bookmarks_count }}</span>
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        {% if request.user not in post.bookmarks.all %}
          <button id="bookmark_add" class="bookmark" name="bookmark" data-id="{{post.id}}"><i class="far fa-bookmark fa-lg"></i></button>
        {% else %}
          <button id="bookmark_add" class="bookmark" name="bookmark" data-id="{{post.id}}"><i class="fad fa-bookmark fa-lg"></i></button>
        {% endif %}
   {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'users:register' %}" id="bookmark_add" class="bookmark"><i class="far fa-bookmark fa-lg"></i></a>
   {% endif %}
```

Problem:
Every time I'm trying to bookmark it's toggling other element. I tried get element by id but it's not working that way too.

tried this but still nothing:

```
this_id = $('#bookmark_add').data("id");  //("id")
                console.log(this_id);
                if (this_id === id) {
                    $("button[this_id]").find('i').toggleClass("fad fa-bookmark far fa-bookmark");
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are in wrong way to get the `id` of the button. Using the `onclick` method of `jquery`, you may get the `id` of the clicked button using `attr` method, like this

```
$('.bookmark').click(function() { 
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

```js
$('.bookmark').click(function() { 
      console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));
    console.log("BEFORE: " + $(this).find('i').attr('class'));
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass("fad fa-bookmark far fa-bookmark");
    console.log("AFTER: " + $(this).find('i').attr('class'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="bookmark_add" class="bookmark" name="bookmark" data-id="1">
    <i class="far fa-bookmark fa-lg"> Test 1</i>
 </button>
 
 <button id="bookmark_add" class="bookmark" name="bookmark" data-id="2">
    <i class="fad fa-bookmark fa-lg"> Test 2</i>
 </button>
```

Even rather than getting `id`, you may toggle the `class` of your `i` element inside the above `click` event definition, like this

```
$('.bookmark').click(function() { 
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass("fad fa-bookmark far fa-bookmark");
});
```

Kindly let me know if this works.

Comment: this.attr gives value in string and data gives value in integer & without id its hitting all bookmarks buttons.

Comment: So @iamcoder, you are using wrong attribute value. It should be `$(this).attr('data-id');`

Comment: @iamcoder also, what do you mean by without id it is hitting all bookmarks buttons. Each button should have an unique ID.

Comment: @iamcoder, use `class` name instead of `id` to have `click` event on all button elements. It will work. Kindly find the updated answer above.

Comment: so now I'm able to toggle all bookmarks with one click how to select only the one I'm clicking.

Comment: @iamcoder, using `$(this)` you may select the one you are clicking. I think you need to try learning `jQuery` a little bit. That would help you a lot. Check out the snippet.

Comment: just created another function calling class of buttons $('.bookmark').click(function(){
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass("far fa-bookmark fad fa-bookmark");
    })  and worked but same line of code not working inside of success: function WHY?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237781/discussion-between-iamcoder-and-tony-montana).